# Measure Customer Retention Calculation in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am calculating the percentage of customers who buy again between 90 and 119 days after the first purchase in BigQuery.

I have used the following code, but the calculation is incorrect.

```
with raw_data as (
select a.client_id
, a.date
, case when b.is_active = true then 1 else 0 end as retention
from table_prod_transactions a
left join table_prod_transactions b
on a.client_id = b.client_id
and b.date >= DATE_ADD(a.date, INTERVAL 90 DAY)
and b.date <= DATE_ADD(a.date, INTERVAL 119 DAY)
where a.date >= '2022-12-01'
and a.is_active = true
and date(a.first_time) = a.date
group by 1,2,3
)
select
date,
sum(retention)/count(distinct client_id)
from raw_data
group by 1
order by 1 asc
```

What am I doing wrong? If I calculate it in the following way, the result is correct, but I don't understand why the first query doesn't work:

```
with a as (
  SELECT distinct a.client_id client_first_purchase
    , a.date
FROM table_prod_transactions a
WHERE  a.date >= '2022-12-01'
  and date(a.first_time) = a.date
  and a.is_active = true
), a2 as (
  SELECT count(distinct a.client_id) client_first_purchase
    , a.date
FROM table_prod_transactions a
WHERE  a.date >= '2022-12-01'
  and date(a.first_time) = a.date
  and a.is_active = true
GROUP BY 2 
)
, d as (
  SELECT a.date
  ,count(distinct d.client_id) active_client
FROM table_prod_transactions d
JOIN a
  ON a.client_first_purchase = d.client_id
WHERE  d.date >= DATE_ADD(a.date, INTERVAL 90 DAY)
  and d.date <= DATE_ADD(a.date, INTERVAL 119 DAY)
  and date(d.first_time) = a.date
  and d.is_active = true
GROUP by 1
)
select a2.date
  , d.active_client/a2.client_first_purchase as m4
FROM 
d
JOIN a2
on  d.date = a2.date
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1 ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first query, you are using a left join between the table and itself, trying to match transactions for each client between 90 and 119 days after their first purchase. However, the way the retention field is calculated doesn't correctly represent the desired retention rate. When you join the table with itself, you are not distinguishing between the first purchase and the subsequent purchases made by the same client within the given time range. This can lead to double-counting, as a client may have multiple transactions within the same time range.